# Can I have multiple sites each with their own adfs claims providers?

Tags: adfs

I have the following sites:

```
https://example.com/ClientA
https://example.com/ClientB
https://example.com/ClientC
```

Right now if I go to https://example.com/ClientA then I'm sent to `https://adfsco.example.com/adfs/ls?...` and there is the claims providers we trust for that site.

Now I'd like to have it so when https://example.com/ClientB is navigated to, the user would see different providers that only matter for that site.

I've seen things about home realm discovery pages, but no step-by-step guide explaining how to actually wire this up. I'm assuming one ADFS can handle this, but not sure how. Is this where relying parties come in?